# Javascript to compare 2 dates in html and change colors

Tags: javascript, python, html, date, flask

I'm creating web app using flask.

/companies.html task is to create a table with some text and dates imported from MongoDb database (hosted in mLab).

Here is the important part of python file:

```
@app.route('/companies', methods=['GET'])
def showCompanies():
    if 'userName' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('start_page'))
    mongoCompanies = mongo.db.companies
    mLabCompanies = [x for x in mongoCompanies.find()]
    return render_template('companies.html', mLabCompanies=mLabCompanies)
```

Here is some sample html:

```
{% for theCompany in mLabCompanies %}
<tr><td>{{theCompany.companyName}}</td> <td {{theCompany.companyShouldGetANumberDate}}</td> <td>{{theCompany.companyShouldGetBNumberDate}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is just a sample. The full version contains 114 cells, where about 20% are dates, 80% is standard text. 
It works well - I mean the table is generated and filled with database records.

Now I need js to compare these dates with today and change their color in html (to red if the date is in the past, or green if the date is in the future).

Here is js which I created.

```
<script>
function checkDate() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var checkedDate = Date.parse(theCompany.textContent);
    if (checkedDate > todayDate){
        theCompany.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        theCompany.style.color = "red"
    }
}
</script>
```

1. JS script doesn't work. What should I change?
2. Where in html I should place JS to make it checks every date and change its color?

Comment: if syntax is not right , missing (

Comment: Open the dev console in your browser, there are some error messages waiting for you.

Comment: Where does theCompany get defined?

Comment: set a class for starters if a date exists so you only target that class

Comment: Deep, Teemu - made some mistakes when simplyfing code for posting here - now it should be ok with all ( ) ; } 

Robbert - in html. Is there a way JS can make use of it for my sake?

Comment: @Nick493 `theCompany` is defined in Python at server-side, right? You can't expect it to be defined at client-side JS. Even if you had defined `theCompany` in JS, how could it be comparable with a date and still being a DOM element?

Comment: @Teemu 
HTML recognise it as I used `return render_template('companies.html', mLabCompanies=mLabCompanies)` in app.py (Python File).

Comment: The question is how it may be recognised in JS script?

Comment: Exactly, HTML! Not as a JS variable. The illogic of the use should be also cleared, though.

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful, what is your input? What do you expect as output? What do you actually get? You shouldn't parse strings with Date.parse (or the Date constructor), their behaviour is mostly implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this is better run on the server to remove the vagaries of local time zones on dates and to remove unnecessary code from clients.

Presumably you have a table with company names and dates in columns, and you want to colour the date cells based on whether the date is in the future or not. So you need a method to firstly get the company cells, then to find the related date cells, then to colour the cell appropriately.

You can get the company names using a query with a selector, I'd suggest that you give the cells a class or data- attribute to distinguish them. Similarly for the date cells so they are easily found. You need to deal with the value in the date cell, which might not be a valid date. You can write small parsing function (see below) or use a library.

Then apply a class to change the colour of the date cell after comparing with "today", e.g.

#### Edit

It seems you only want to deal with the date cells and ignore the company cells. The following is an edited version to do that, it just needs 2 lines commented out and a small change to a third (original lines remain and have been commented out to show changes).

```js
/* Parse ISO formatted date, e.g. 2017-06-30 as local
** @param {string} s - date in ISO 8601 format
** @returns {Date} will be an invalid date if string is not a valid date
*/
function parseISOasLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0],--b[1],b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Edited to only deal with dateCells

window.onload = function(){
  // Get all the company and date cells
//  var companyCells = document.querySelectorAll('.companyName');
  var dateCells = document.querySelectorAll('.companyDate');
  var today = new Date();
  // For each company cell, get the date cell and apply a class
  // based on whether the date is in the future or not
  // Invalid dates get the same class as past dates
//  [].forEach.call(companyCells, function(cell, i) {
  [].forEach.call(dateCells, function(dateCell) {

//    var dateCell = dateCells[i];
    var d = parseISOasLocal(dateCell.textContent);
    if (!isNaN(d) && d > today) {
      dateCell.classList.add('futureDate');
    } else {
      dateCell.classList.add('pastDate');
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.futureDate {
  color: black;
  background-color: green;
}
.pastDate {
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  border-left: 1px solid #9999;
  border-top: 1px solid #9999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border-right: 1px solid #9999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9999;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="companyName">Company A</td>
    <td class="companyDate">2016-07-15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="companyName">Company B</td>
    <td class="companyDate">2017-07-15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="companyName">Company C</td>
    <td class="companyDate">No date</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

The above deals with invalid values in the date cell (e.g. for Company C), but relies on the company and date being in the same sequence. Invalid dates get the same class as past dates, they could be singled out using `if (isNaN(d))` and given a different class.

Using spread syntax, the onload function body could be:

```
var today = new Date();
[...document.querySelectorAll('.companyDate')].forEach(cell => 
  cell.classList.add(parseISOasLocal(cell.textContent) > today? 'futureDate':'pastDate')
);
```

but the web may not be ready for that just yet.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but produces one error. The whole column is red instead of one cell. Now I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: I figured it. There is no error. The whole column got red because No date according to this script gets red color. 
So that's it - this case is finished.

Comment: How to change this function if there is no "companyName" cells? Only "companyDate" cells in html table.

Comment: @Nick493—you can remove any reference to *companyName* cell and iterate over the *companyDate* cells, which is actually simpler. I assumed you included the *companyDate* cells because you were going to do something else with them not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript has several syntax errors. It looks like you're going to need to convert a date string kept in `theCompany.textContent` to a Date in order to compare it to `todayDate`. To do that, you'll want to use **[`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)**.

Here's a corrected version:

```
<script>
  function checkDate() {
    var todayDate = new Date();

    // Depending on what "theCompany" is, this still may not work
    // It looks like it is an HTML element, in which case, you will
    // need to extract the content of the element (i.e. theCompany.textContent)
    // and then you'll need to make a new data from that string of data
    // before you try to compare it to "todayDate" with 
    // "Date.parse(valid date string here)"
    var checkedDate = Date.parse(theCompany.textContent);
    if (checkedDate > todayDate){
         theCompany.style.color = "green";
    } else {
         thCompany.style.color = "red"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How about using `theCompany` from Python?

Comment: how would this check all? syntax is only part of OP's issue

Comment: @Teemu I don't know anything about Python, so that's why I'm saying that it looks like `Date.parse()` is needed. The OP is setting `theCompany.style` so it seems that `theCompany` is a DOM object.

Comment: Neither do I, but `{% for theCompany in mLabCompanies %}` in the first snippet shows, that `theCompany` is defined at server-side?

Comment: @Teemu I do see that, but the fact that the OP is trying to set `theCompany.style` leads me to believe that it's a DOM element. Perhaps it is a DOM element coming from Python? Or, perhaps that line isn't getting it from Python, but instead is sending it to Python?

Comment: Scott Marcus - You're right. It's just HTML element. 
I'll go with your advice and change code in my post so others will understand it. 

Teemu - also sounds like a good idea. Do you know how I can use Python variable in JS? 


charlietfl - True. I still need solution to check all.

Comment: @Nick493 When you say "check all dates", do you mean scan the document for any/all **strings** that appear to match a date format?

Comment: In app.py I used:
    return render_template('companies.html', mLabCompanies=mLabCompanies)
to export it to html file.

Comment: @Scott Marcus - Yes. It's one of the solutions which will suit me.

Comment: Please don't suggest using *Date.parse*, it's largely implementation dependent and the OP hasn't indicated the string or format they're trying to parse. I can't see that you've suggested anything there isn't already in the OP.

Comment: Well, since the OP code wouldn't even compile due to syntax errors and since I've provided a mechanism that certainly can solve the date problem, I'd have to disagree with your sentiment.

Comment: The OP fixed the syntax errors, this doesn't address [issues with *Date.parse*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) nor answer "*checks every date and change it's [sic] color*.

Comment: @RobG Take it easy there. My answer was posted BEFORE the errors were corrected and without the information that we now have. Move along.